# State of the art in predicting the outcome of a competitive game?

Tags: classification, games

For games where $K$ players on team 1 compete against $K$ players on team 2, and we assume that the outcome is solely dependent on who is playing against whom, the simplest method of prediction I know of is logistic regression with a feature vector $x$, where $x$ has $N$ elements for each of the $N$ players, and 
$$x_i = \begin{cases} 1 
 & \text{player } i \text{ is in team 1} \\ -1 & \text{player } i \text{ is in team 2} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

In my use case, this method is able to get 66% cross-validation accuracy, and for this type of feature vector, logistic regression seems to outperform other classifiers. However, I wonder if there are other models entirely. The idea that some players are strong counters to other players could be encoded in some sort of latent factor model where $u_i$ are the strengths of player $i$ and $v_j$ are the weaknesses of player $j$, then $u_i^{\top} v_j$ would encode how much of an advantage player $i$ has over player $j$. However, I don't know of any techniques that actually leverage this.

For this type of game, what is the state of the art in predicting winners?